# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(A)[ze -> ze -> ze -> ze -> ze] after angular upgrade to 14

Tags: angular

Please help on finding the error, code is compiling successfully with ng serve and application is partially working. however when I am trying to load a LazyLoad module getting error - ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(A)[ze -> ze -> ze -> ze -> ze]' SO not able to identify what is root cause, if there is some dependency missing then how would I know name and details. Your suggestion is really appriciated.

I am not getting clue/root cause which module/service I am missing to inject.

Comment: Run your app in devmode, this will keep the symbol and help the debugging

Comment: thanks however still not getting idea which Service is missing!

Comment: What error do you get in devMode ?

Comment: I am getting same error (NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(A)[ze -> ze -> ze -> ze -> ze]' ) when ng serve on local environment.

Comment: Serve is not devMode. Check you angular.json.

Comment: Thanks, I got the problem by adding -      "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }, in angular.json and run in development mode.